# javax.xml.xpath cannot find element in xml w3c document

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following xml stored in w3c.dom.Document: docXml

```
<sqph:contractplaceholders xmlns:sqph="http://schemas.company.com/office/placeholders/v1">
    <sqph:ContractMgmt_ContractNumber debugId="ContractMgmt_ContractNumber" id="ContractMgmt_ContractNumber">test418TBD</sqph:ContractMgmt_ContractNumber>
</sqph:contractplaceholders>
```

i'm trying to recover the text inside it with:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/sqph:contractplaceholders[1]/sqph:ContractMgmt_ContractNumber[1]/text()");
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(docXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
int listLenght = nodeList.getLength();
org.w3c.dom.Node node = (org.w3c.dom.Node) expr.evaluate(docXml, XPathConstants.NODE);
String str = (String) expr.evaluate(docXml, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

nodeList does not have the data, node is null and str is empty. What could i be missing?

Comment: namespace in xpath factory

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/xpath-namespace-resolution-example/

Comment: implementing the namespace resolver worked, ty.